# Google App Engine NDB Read Operation Optimization

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm looking to optimize my read operations in my GAE python app. I don't want to go over my free quota. I'm basically storing data every so often. A lot of the data i'm getting might be duplicated so i have to check it before i store it. This results in a lot of read ops and some write ops. Here is how i'm doing it now:

```
#data is a JSON data list with hundreds of items 
for item in data:
  record = InfoDB.get_by_id(item['id'])
  if record:
     continue 
  else:
     entity = InfoDB(id=item['id'], data=item['data']).put()
```

Here is one way i thought of lowering the read ops. Though i'm not 100% sure if that's true. I'm thinking it may perform a read op every time the loop iterates.

```
#data is a JSON data list with hundreds of items
flag = False
db = InfoDB.query().fetch()
for item in data:
  for record in db:
    if record.id == item.id:
      flag = True

  if flag is True:
    continue
  else:
    entity = InfoDB(id=item['id'], data=item['data']).put()
```

Is the above method actually saving me read operations since it's essentially just grabbing the entire datastore and then using a for loop to process the entire set every iteration? I realize this is slower but i don't see how else i could accomplish this efficiently.

Any other ideas?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, this is using NDB. Not the older DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed method will result in many more read operations, not less, because now you read *all* entities, whether you need them or not.

This is how you can optimize it, if you can override the existing entities:

```
for item in data:
    InfoDB(id=item['id'], data=item['data']).put()
```

If you cannot override the existing entities, you should use a [keys-only query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Keys_only_queries):

```
for key in query.iter(keys_only=True):
```

Keys-only queries are now free, as opposed to fetching complete entities.

Comment: Interesting. I did find that `keys_only=True` should be in the fetch() rather than query(). That said, i couldn't figure out how to do a query base don key. The closest i came to was `InfoDB.query(InfoDB._key == 'item['id']').fetch(keys_only=True)`. However that doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you pass the key and try to retrieve a key?

Comment: Here is a link to keys_only query in docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Keys_only_queries

Comment: I guess i just don't understand the query() function. Also, i'm using NDB not the older DB as you linked.

Comment: OK, this is the link to NDB queries: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries

Comment: I just realized my mistake. The query, when set to keys_only, will simply return a list of keys. Then i just need to see if the key in question matches any key in the list of keys returned. This makes much more sense. I was trying to use the query to return the record based on key. Which i'm still not sure how to do... But for my purposes the above would work.

Comment: Just a (possibly?) important note: keys only queries are not totally free. They cost 1 read operation per query as opposed to costing 1 read operation + N small operations where N is the number of results + number of results skipped by an offset. Also, if you have not set up billing, you will be limited to a 50,000 small operations per day quota.

Answer (score 2):

If you know all the keys, do a `entities = db.get([list of keys])` or `entities = ndb.get_multi([list of keys])`- which from your sample you do know all the id's.

This is far more efficient.

Then do a `db.put(entities)` or `ndb.put_multi(entities)`

Comment: Just to confirm, that's for NDB and not the older DB?

Comment: No that is for db.  Read the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#get

Comment: Oops your using ndb, then use the ndb equivalent ndb.get_multi and ndb.put_multi. - See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions

Comment: using db as a variable threw me, I for some reason read everything as if your using db ;-)